# How to use mongodb with grails 2.4.4?

Tags: mongodb, grails, gorm-mongodb

I have been trying to use mongodb with grails. To do that add the following code in the plugin part in BuildConfig.groovy

```
compile ":mongodb:3.0.3"
```

Then I have changed DataSource.groovy into the follwings:

```
          grails {
            mongo {
              host = "localhost"
              port = 27107
              username = "user"
              password="secretpassword"
              databaseName = "physicians"
            }
          }
```

But it causes compilation error as followings:

```
Error |
2015-07-14 14:29:53,412 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTransactionManager' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoBean' while setting bean property 'mongo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{} after 10000 ms
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTransactionManager' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoBean' while setting bean property 'mongo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{} after 10000 ms
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTransactionManager' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoBean' while setting bean property 'mongo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{} after 10000 ms
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoBean' while setting bean property 'mongo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{} after 10000 ms
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoBean' while setting bean property 'mongo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{} after 10000 ms
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{} after 10000 ms
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MongoTimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{} after 10000 ms
->>   87 | getServer in com.mongodb.BaseCluster
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    654 | getServer in com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector
|     39 | access$300 in     ''
|    503 | getConnection in com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort
|    451 | get . . . in     ''
|    624 | authenticate in com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector
|    195 | doAuthenticate in com.mongodb.DBApiLayer
|    765 | authenticateCommandHelper in com.mongodb.DB
|    721 | authenticate in     ''
|    149 | afterPropertiesSet in org.grails.datastore.gorm.mongo.bean.factory.GMongoFactoryBean
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Can you please tell me how to fix the error. Btw, the tutorial that i have been following can be found in below link :
http://blog.mongodb.org/post/18510469058/grails-in-the-land-of-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

your server is not reachable, what you can clearly see in the exception trace:

> Caused by MongoTimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{} after 10000 ms

Comment: I am a beginner in grails. can you please tell me what to do to solve this problem?

Comment: check that the mongo server is up and running and is reachable via `localhost:27107`

Answer (score 0):

So here is what's happening:

First off all you need to confirm if your Mongo service is running either by just entering `mongo` command (and see if you land to Mongo shell) or by `ps -A | grep mongod`.

In any case if the MongoDB service is running then you first need to start your service.

`sudo service mongod start` # For Ubuntu & CentOS
# OR
`mongod --config /etc/mognod.conf`

(I've given you the example for Ubuntu & CentOS. Read [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/) if you are using different OS.)

Now, after you started service or confirmed that MongoDB server is up & running you need to do `run-app`.

One thing I saw problematic in your question in the port number i.e. `27107` instead of `27017`. I'm not sure if this is by mistake in the question or you have added this to your Grails `DataSource.groovy` file.
By default, MongoDB runs on the port number `27017` (although you can configure it). So this can be your problem.

So change that port number to `27017` and then do `grails run-app`. This should work.